# Replace element in list with white space

Tags: python

Is it possible to check element of list? If it has the same word as in "test01.txt" then replace with space?

test01.txt:

```
to
her
too
a
for
```

In the codes:

```
with open('C:/test01.txt') as words:
    ws = words.read().splitlines()
with open('C:/test02.txt') as file_modify4:
    for x in file_modify4:
        sx = map(str.strip, x.split("\t"))
        ssx = sx[0].split(" ")
        print ssx
```

Results from "print ssx":

```
['wow']
['listens', 'to', 'her', 'music']
['too', 'good']
['a', 'film', 'for', 'stunt', 'scheduling', 'i', 'think']
['really', 'enjoyed']
```

How to replace the element in ssx?

Expected result:

```
['wow']
['listens', ' ', ' ', 'music']
[' ', 'good']
[' ', 'film', ' ', 'stunt', 'scheduling', 'i', 'think']
['really', 'enjoyed']
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehensions; storing the words in a set first for faster testing:

```
ws = set(ws)

# ...
    ssx = [w if w not in ws else ' ' for w in ssx]
```

or, as a complete solution:

```
with open('C:/test01.txt') as words:
    ws = set(words.read().splitlines())

with open('C:/test02.txt') as file_modify4:
    for x in file_modify4:
        ssx = [w if w not in ws else ' ' for w in x.strip().split('\t')[0].split()]
        print ssx
```

Answer (score 1):

The naive solution is:

```
new_ssx = []
for word in ssx:
    if word in ws:
        new_ssx.append(' ')
    else:
        new_ssx.append(word)
```

Of course whenever you have an empty list that you just append to in a loop, you can turn it into a list comprehension:

```
new_ssx = [' ' if word in ws else word for word in ssx]
```

If `ws` is more than a few words, you probably want to turn it into a `set` to make the lookups faster.

So, putting it all together:

```
with open('C:/test01.txt') as words:
    ws = set(words.read().splitlines())
with open('C:/test02.txt') as file_modify4:
    for x in file_modify4:
        sx = map(str.strip, x.split("\t"))
        ssx = sx[0].split(" ")
        new_ssx = [' ' if word in ws else word for word in ssx]
        print new_ssx
```